# java generic how to use generic in constructor

Tags: java, android

```
public class DbManager<T extends Dao> {

    public DbManager(Context c) {
        setCreateDatabaseScript(T);
    }

    public void setCreateDatabaseScript(T dao) {
        this.createDatabaseScript = ((Dao)dao).createTable();
    }

    //..
}
```

how can I inside constructor call setCreateDatabaseScript. I try like in example but not working. What is correct syntax?

Comment: What do you expect `setCreateDatabaseScript(T)` to mean? `T` is a *type parameter*, not a value to be passed to a method...

Answer (score 1):

`setCreateDatabaseScript(T dao)` needs instance of `T` so you probably should pass it in constructor

```
public DbManager(Context c, T dao) {
    setCreateDatabaseScript(dao);
}
```

Also since `T extends Dao` you don't need to cast it to Dao, just use `dao.createTable();`

Answer (score 0):

```
public DbManager(Context c) {
    setCreateDatabaseScript(T);
}
```

You have to call setCreateDatabaseScript with an object of type T as parameter, not just with T.

Answer (score 0):

The object, T, has never been declared or instantiated when it is used in your constructor.